# Stop warning message after first occurrence?

Tags: vb.net

I have a some code which will check to see if any values are marked as 0 on a form, each text box has its own unique warning message. Currently if all 3 values are 0, 3 warnings will appear one after the other. The code is below

```
If txt_quantity.Text = 0 Then MsgBox(Prompt:="Please enter a correct quantity") Else 
If txt_quantitysupplied.Text = 0 Then MsgBox(Prompt:="Please enter a correct quantity supplied") Else 
If txt_value.Text = 0 Then MsgBox(Prompt:="Please enter a correct value") Else
```

How do I amend the code so that as soon as one message box is diplayed it stops checking the other conditions, so ideally if there are 3 errors it will display one warning and then start the process again when the user next commits. Hopefully this makes sense, I'm having difficulty putting this into words.

Comment: Put the logic in a IsValid() function then exit the function after the msgbox? (return True at the end)

Comment: Rather than show just one message with one error, consider showing 1 message with *all* the errors

Comment: The [ErrorProvider Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) is a way to display errors to users without a barrage of modal MsgBoxes

Comment: @Plutonix - Beat me to it again - agreed on the ErrorProvider. Much neater for end users.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the error tests independent of each other and append to an error string which you then display if necessary.

The following pseudo code illustrates this:

```
string errorMessage = ""

If txt_quantity.Text = 0 Then errorMessage += "\nPlease enter a correct quantity"
If txt_quantitysupplied.Text = 0 Then errorMessage += "\nPlease enter a correct quantity supplied"
If txt_value.Text = 0 Then errorMessage += "\nPlease enter a correct value"

If errorMessage.Length > 0 Then
    MsgBox(Prompt:=errorMessage)
End If
```

You will probably need to do more formatting of the error message to ensure that each error is displayed on a single line and the whole thing lines up correctly.